# How to add source doc title to each chunk of document in llamaindex

Tags: chatbot, langchain, large-language-model, llama-index

If I understand correctly how llamaindex works, it splits each long document to several smaller chunks, and then passes them as context part in LLM prompt. I am following this [guide](https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/stable/end_to_end_tutorials/chatbots/building_a_chatbot.html#how-to-build-a-chatbot)
I am trying to create chatbot that is capable of discussing movies, its knowledge base is wikipedia plots. So, I assume it is crucial for chatbot to see not only relevant part of the plot, but also a title, so it can tell what film the user is talking about.
How am I adding title to each chunk, so the context looks like below?

```
{title}
{relevant plot chunk}
```

Comment: you can modify your chunk logic and add additional text title and then pass them as context. alternatively, if you are using vector database you can add title as metadata

Comment: @ZKS could you please provide more info on how could I achieve this? I did not found exact way for this in docs

Comment: which vector db you are using

Comment: I am using llamaindex built in index

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample code for dealing with metadata. It depends upon you data structure. In below example year is being added as metadata

```
    years = [2022, 2021, 2020, 2019]
    UnstructuredReader = download_loader("UnstructuredReader", refresh_cache=True)

    loader = UnstructuredReader()
    doc_set = {}
    all_docs = []
    for year in years:
        year_docs = loader.load_data(file=Path(f'./data/UBER/UBER_{year}.html'), split_documents=False)
        # insert year metadata into each year
        for d in year_docs:
            d.metadata = {"year": year}
        doc_set[year] = year_docs
        all_docs.extend(year_docs)
```